# Delay turn ON circuit using 555

Tags: mosfet, 555

I want to set a delay of around 5s between power supply turning ON and my circuit getting power.

[image]

Here is the circuit I have come up with:

[image: circuit]

[Datasheet of mosfet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ON%20Semiconductor%20PDFs/NTD4979N.pdf)

I am using a 555 timer to set the startup delay and N-channel mosfet to supply power to the load. Most of the through hole mosfets have Rds minimum at around 10 V. Luckily I had 12V supply readily available so I am using 12 V to switch the 5V line as shown above. P4 is input and P3 is load.

Is my circuit correct?

Besides initial turn ON delay, I want the circuit to reset when power is disconnected (in half a min or so. if it happens within 1-2 seconds, it will be even better). To achieve this, I have put R7 (100K) discharge resistor on the capacitor which will discharge it and get the circuit in working state again. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You want it to wait five seconds, turn on, then in 1-2 seconds turn off again? If so, look up using the 555 in monostable one-shot mode. As in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/245753/15805).

Comment: No, I want wait 5 seconds then turn ON and keep it turned ON until power is disconnected.

Comment: Ah, so the reset just means that it's ready to use a few seconds after you disconnect the power?

Comment: Yes (random text to reach min word count for posting this comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit looks good.

If you want faster reset of the circuit move `R7` to between `12V` and `GND` and reduce its resistance... when the `12V` is turned off `C3` will discharge through `D1` and the new `R7`

Comment: Will it not affect the charging process? I am sorry but I am not able to visualize.

Comment: the new location of R7 is connected to +12V and Gnd,  it only affects the capacitor when the 12V is turned off. when the 12V is on it justs sits there making heat.