# How can I delay a pulse by 0.5 s?

Tags: pulse

I asked something similar [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/415378/generating-a-delayed-pulse-of-0-5sec-with-one-555-timer-upon-powering-up-the-cir).
Now, when I make my circuit, I've seen that I don't need something that gives a pulse after being powered-up, but I just need a delayed pulse.

I know nothing about electronics, so here my (easy?) question.

Which circuit do I need, when I want to give a input pulse with a push-button (16V DC), a delay of 0.5 s and then an output pulse?
This pulse doesn't have to be the same length.

I'm open to everything. I know that, in my previous question, the solution was with a 555 timer. Now it is not necessary. I only need a (cheap) circuit that does the things I want.

EDIT: I know this is more or less a duplicate of my previous question, and my english is not very good.
The point is: I know nothing about electronics and I know the circuit I need will be similar to what I already have in the previous answers. I know that. But I'm not capable to adapt that solution, sorry. Is there someone so kind to help me. A solution with two 555 timers is good, but will someone be so kind to make a scheme? Please?

Comment: An easy way to do this is to use a cascaded sequence of two monostable 555s, where the falling edge of one triggers the other to output a pulse.

Comment: A 555 *IS* a cheap solution.

Comment: So the price of a 555 has become an issue?

Comment: While it's cool that you come here to ask about circuits, the goal must always be to try and understand the answers you've gotten. You already have a pulse delayer, and give no reasonable reason that you need another, but still want us to design yet another one for you. Don't. You have a solution that you should be able to adapt.

Comment: You can get microcontrollers which cost less than a 555 timer and would do the job admirably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a delayed pulse of 0,5sec with one 555 timer upon powering up the circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/415378/generating-a-delayed-pulse-of-0-5sec-with-one-555-timer-upon-powering-up-the-cir) . Voting to close as a duplicate as the issue here is not meaningfully different than your previous question, only the trigger cause changes, but nothing in your present question indicates that the trigger could not also be the rise of some signal.

Comment: I think the modern solution for a beginner is to just use an arduino. A knockoff is 10 bucks, and it will be fairly accurate and easy to adjust with no fuss.